# Show that $f \vartriangle g$ is not a function.

Tags: functions

This is an exercise from Velleman's "How To Prove It".

> Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are functions from $A$ to $B$ and $f \neq g$. Show that $f \vartriangle g$ is not a function.

I was trying to reach a contradiction by supposing that $f \vartriangle g$ is a function. Since $f \neq g$, I broke the proof into cases based on $(a,b) \in f$ but $(a,b) \notin g$ or $(a,b) \in g$ but $(a,b) \notin f$. I'm failing to find a contradiction though. Any hints?

Comment: What is $\vartriangle$ in this context?

Comment: @marcelgoh The symmetric difference. So $f \vartriangle g$ = $f\setminus g \cup g\setminus f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** The condition $f \neq g$ is precisely that there is an $a \in A$ such that $f(a) \neq g(a)$.

> **Additional hint** For such an element $a \in A$, what can you say about the elements of the form $(a, \,\cdot\,)$ in $f \bigtriangleup g$?

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving a concrete example, but this should illustrate the general case.
Let $A = \{0,1\} = B$, $f = \{(0,1),(1,0)\}$ and $g = \{(0,0), (1,0)\}.$ Then
$A\vartriangle B = \{(0,1),(0,0)\}$, but this is not a function, since it is not well-defined.

**UPDATE:** Travis Willse gave an excellent hint as well. Between his answer and mine, you should have a clear approach.